# Pandas: Conditional joining of column from same dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My goal is to create an excel-vlookup equivalent in python which takes the value of the past month and places it to a new column ['new'] next to the current month.

Given the ['id'] as key column, how can I match these two pairs with each other? It appears to me as if it is a merge (left-join) with a condition.

From This:

```
id       month  value
01     current    123
02     current    234
03     current    345
01     prev1      543
02     prev1      432
03     prev1      321
01     prev2      678
02     prev2      789
03     prev2      890
```

To this:

```
id       month  value  new
01     current    123  543
02     current    234  432
03     current    345  321
01     prev1      543  678
02     prev1      432  789
03     prev1      321  890
01     prev2      678  NaN
02     prev2      789  NaN
03     prev2      890  NaN
```

months: only current, prev1, and prev2 exist

id: hundreds of ids exist

I would like to avoid using any month numbers and would just stick to current, prev1, prev2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('id').value.shift(-1)
df
Out[410]: 
   id    month  value    new
0   1  current    123  543.0
1   2  current    234  432.0
2   3  current    345  321.0
3   1    prev1    543  678.0
4   2    prev1    432  789.0
5   3    prev1    321  890.0
6   1    prev2    678    NaN
7   2    prev2    789    NaN
8   3    prev2    890    NaN
```